# Is expect tool availabe for ARM platform

Tags: shell-script, utilities, arm, expect

I need to get `expect` (tool for automating interactive applications) for the ARM platform. Is it a readily cross compiled to ARM and is it available? I tried googling but was unable to get the  binaries.

Comment: Are you using some distribution? Debian, for example, has [`expect` for `armhf` and `armel`](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=expect) architectures; a `*.deb` file can be handled as a `tgz` archive.

Comment: `expect` is in raspbian (debian for the ARM11, aka armv6, raspberry pi; it uses hard floats).  I would think it would not be too hard to cross compile as it probably does not depend on much.

Comment: Its custom build with the https://svn.eaton.com/toolkit-docs/ for pandaboard ARM9

Comment: Was looking for a ARM binary if its there it will save time.

Answer (score 0):

expect is written with Tcl, and there are Tcl interpreters for ARM.

Comment: Since i have a custom version of linux. I Would like to know how to check it TCL interpreter is  there or not. ( I thought of checking this before cross compiling expect for ARM). Thanks

Comment: @m4n07,expect embeds a TCL interpreter. You don't need another TCL interpreter in addition to expect, however the `expect` commands you find in random distributions might be dynamically linked to `libtcl` in which case, you'll need to get the TCL packages from those distributions.